# Zoom beyond 21 zoom level with googlemaps api Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to zoom beyond the 21 max zoom level provide by the googlemaps api on Android ?
I have my own pictures with a TileOverlay, so i would like to zoom over 21 on my own pictures on the map.

Thanks !

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Did you somehow managed to transcend the zoom limit of 21?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution yet..

Comment: In OSM it is possible to override this limit , so I was hoping it would also be possible with Google

Comment: Could you stop talking to say nothing ? It is useless to say that OSM is not Google map. If you want to stop you at any limit is your choice, but some have the ambition to push the limits.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum zoom level is 21 and there is no indicated way to surpass this.

As proof, I'm going to give you an example using Javascript but the same concept holds true to Android as well.

This is a map with zoom level set to 21:
[click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shdqznt1/4/)

`var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 21,
    center: myLatLng
  });`

This is a map with zoom level set to 23: [click here for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3u3nkoh8/2/)

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 23,
    center: myLatLng
  });
```

You will notice between the two that nothing has changed, there is no way to go beyond the limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already know the limit of 21, that is why i ask if there exist a way to pass this limit

Comment: None that I know of.